# Drawing multiple objects in webgl

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl-extensions

I am WebGL beginner and trying to draw multiple objects, I have already rendered one, now going for multiple. 
There are very less tutorial for multiple object rendering, the one that i could find was on this link http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html

I tried changing code according to it but it do not work, Could some one please correct the problems and give the solution with explanation 
that what is wrong in my try ?

My full code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script class="WebGL">
        var gl;
        function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
        {
            var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vs, vertexShader);
            gl.compileShader(vs);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));
            //////
            var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fs, fragmentShader);
            gl.compileShader(fs);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));
            program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vs);
            gl.attachShader(program, fs);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
            return program;
        }
        function createShaderFromScriptElement(gl , shaderName)
        {
            var Shader = document.getElementById(shaderName).firstChild.nodeValue;
            return Shader;
        }
        function start()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            if (!gl) { alert("error while GL load"); }

              var vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
              var fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");

              var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

            gl.useProgram(program);
            var colorMult = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "u_colorMult");
            var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");


            // Our uniforms for each thing we want to draw
            var sphereUniforms = {
                u_colorMult: [0.5, 1, 0.5, 1],
                u_matrix: makeIdentity(),
            };
            var cubeUniforms = {
                u_colorMult: [1, 0.5, 0.5, 1],
                u_matrix: makeIdentity(),
            };
            var coneUniforms = {
                u_colorMult: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1],
                u_matrix: makeIdentity(),
            };

            // The translation for each object.
            var sphereTranslation = [0, 0, 0];
            var cubeTranslation = [-40, 0, 0];
            var coneTranslation = [40, 0, 0];


            var sphereXRotation = time;
            var sphereYRotation = time;
            var cubeXRotation = -time;
            var cubeYRotation = time;
            var coneXRotation = time;
            var coneYRotation = -time;

            // ------ Draw the sphere --------

            gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

            // Setup all the needed attributes.
            setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo.attribSetters, sphereBufferInfo);

            sphereUniforms.u_matrix = computeMatrix(
                viewMatrix,
                projectionMatrix,
                sphereTranslation,
                sphereXRotation,
                sphereYRotation);

            // Set the uniforms we just computed
            setUniforms(programInfo.uniformSetters, sphereUniforms);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, sphereBufferInfo.numElements);

            // ------ Draw the cube --------

            // Setup all the needed attributes.
            setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo.attribSetters, cubeBufferInfo);

            cubeUniforms.u_matrix = computeMatrix(
                viewMatrix,
                projectionMatrix,
                cubeTranslation,
                cubeXRotation,
                cubeYRotation);

            // Set the uniforms we just computed
            setUniforms(programInfo.uniformSetters, cubeUniforms);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, cubeBufferInfo.numElements);

            // ------ Draw the cone --------

            // Setup all the needed attributes.
            setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo.attribSetters, coneBufferInfo);

            coneUniforms.u_matrix = computeMatrix(
                viewMatrix,
                projectionMatrix,
                coneTranslation,
                coneXRotation,
                coneYRotation);

            // Set the uniforms we just computed
            setUniforms(programInfo.uniformSetters, coneUniforms);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, coneBufferInfo.numElements);
        }
    </script>
    <script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        // Passed in from the vertex shader.
        varying vec4 v_color;
        uniform vec4 u_colorMult;

        void main() 
        {
            gl_FragColor = v_color * u_colorMult;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        uniform vec4 u_color;

        void main()
        {
        gl_FragColor = u_color;  // green
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <div style="text-align: center">

    </div>
    <table style="width:100%; height: 10%;">       
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px; max-width:200px; ">
                <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
            </td>
            <td style="width:200px; max-width:200px; background-color:gray; ">
                <canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please explain me the solution so that i will understand and it will remain with me for future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLSL shaders have 3 types of variables:

- **Uniforms** are set by the host app and remain constant across all vertices/fragments in a single draw call.
- **Attributes** are set per-vertex by the host app, and read only in the vertex shader.
- **Varyings** are only ever *written to* by the vertex shader, and read by the fragment shader, after interpolation in the rasterizer.

So here are some problems I can spot in your code:

- You're attempting to read a "varying" in the vertex shader, use a vertex attribute instead.
- You're calling functions like `makeIdentity` but I don't see them declared, edit your page to pull in the appropriate matrix library to supply these functions.
- I don't see any actual vertex data being passed into WebGL here.  Nothing will be rendered without vertex data.

The article you linked to in your question has a [standalone demo](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-multiple-objects-manual.html) that you can `View source` on to see a complete working example.  Note that it pulls in some matrix math helper libraries at the top, and calls functions like `createCubeVertices` to create vertex data.

Also check out [lesson 2 of Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134) where they apply vertex colors to some polygons.  You may want to work your way through [all of the lessons](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217) there.

Also, most developers find they don't need to build their own 3D engine from scratch.  Consider learning one of the [existing WebGL frameworks](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions#Frameworks) that can hide the low-level details of WebGL.  Of these, [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) is a popular place to start.  If you don't need a deep understanding of all the low-level details, this will save you a lot of time and effort.